# Pytest: Print to console and capture output in the junit report?

Tags: junit, pytest

This will capture stdout in junit but will not print it

```
py.test --verbose simpletest.py --junit-xml=test.xml
```

This will not capture stdout in junit and will print it

```
py.test --verbose --capture=no simpletest.py --junit-xml=test.xml
```

How do I allow pytest to print to stdout and print stdout to junit xml?

Comment: I would look into using conftest.py to set up a file object multiplexer that would sit in sys.stdout and send output to original sys.stdout (i.e., your console) and also a disk file that can later be incorporated into test.xml.

Comment: @TomBarron Sounds promising. I tried searching for an example of what you're describing without any results. Would you share an example or a link that may get me on the right track?

Comment: Just saw this. I'll try to put something together this evening.

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/pastebin.py. It sends pytest output to pastebin. It might be possible to use something like this but rewrite it to send the captured output to more than one destination. It turned out to be more challenging than I expected. :)

Answer (score 4):

The following command can be used to print output to stdout/stderr and also capture to the junit report (starting in pytest 5.4):

`python -m pytest --capture=tee-sys -o junit_logging=all --junit-xml=pytest_unit.xml tests/test_something.py`

Docs for [--capture=tee-sys](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html) and [junit_logging=all](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-junit_logging)

Comment: This is the best answer. I'd also note the junit_log_passing_tests option (https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-junit_log_passing_tests), which you may wish to disable to avoid bloating your junit files.

Answer (score 2):

For pytest-2.3.5 we can generate a similar junit-xml output

```
pytest --verbose --junitxml=filepath\\file.xml file.py
```

I tested this with file.py having pytest tests. `--verbose` command line argument is just to ouput detailed test results on console.

I also tried to generate a similar xml file by invoking my test script from another python script

```
pytest.main(["--verbose","--junitxml=filepath\\file.xml","filepath\\file.py"])
```